# How can I remove certain words from a line but put the rest of it into a string/variable with batch?

Tags: string, batch-file

I am making a batch program that needs to take this line in a .txt file:

```
Random Characters: 93h4-283ed-93j2-je82
```

and take ONLY the `93h4-283ed-93j2-je82` and put it into a variable. (its the first line in a txt file)

How can I do this? I have looked around on the interwebs but most of the answers I found didn't work the way I wanted.

I looked around on Stack Overflow and other sources but they made the entire line disappear if it contained some words, whereas I only want to take a piece of the line and put it into a batch variable/string.

**text.txt**

```
Random Characters: 93h4-283ed-93j2-je82
```

**textf.txt should be**

```
93h4-283ed-93j2-je82
```

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please share your coding attempts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based purely on what you've provided, i.e. Split the first line of `text.txt` keeping everything after the first sequence of the two characters, **<kbd>:</kbd>**  and output to `textf.txt`.

```bat
@<"text.txt" (Set/P "Var="&Call Echo(%%Var:*: =%%)>"textf.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to grab `Random Characters` as a string, This can be done very easy in an `for` loop. We use `type text.txt` to get the file displayed line by line to a variable. From there we look for lines containing `Random Characters:` by using `find /I "Random Characters:"`. Finally we can extract the Numbers by using `"tokens=1-2,3* delims= "` inside the `for` loop.

```
Rem | Get .txt To String
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('type text.txt') DO (

    Rem | Find The First "Random Characters" Line
    for /f "tokens=1-2,3* delims= " %%B in ('echo %%A^| find /I "Random Characters:"') do (

        Rem | Set String
        Set "String=%%D"

        Rem | Break Loop
        Goto Finished

    )
)

:Finished

Echo %String%
```

---

If you're looking to update an text file and remove the `Random Characters:` then we can add a replace function to edit the text file.

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem | Configuration
Set "FileLocation=text.txt"

Rem | Get .txt To String
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('type !FileLocation!') DO (

    Rem | Find The First "Random Characters" Line
    for /f "tokens=1-2,3* delims= " %%B in ('echo %%A^| find /I "Random Characters:"') do (

        Rem | Set SearchText & ReplaceText
        Set "SearchText=%%A"
        Set "ReplaceText=%%D"

        Rem | Break Loop
        Goto EditString

    )
)
goto :EOF

:EditString

REM | Make sure we only edit the Random Characters: line.
FOR /F "delims=" %%n IN ('findstr /n "^" %FileLocation%') DO (
    SET line=%%n
    SET Modified=!line:%SearchText%=%ReplaceText%!
    SET Modified=!Modified:*:=!

    REM | Output the entire edited INI to a temporary file.
    >> %FileLocation%.TEMP ECHO(!Modified!
)

Rem | Delete Original File, Restore New
DEL %FileLocation%
REN %FileLocation%.TEMP %FileLocation%

Goto :EOF
```

**Input Raw Text File:**

```
Random Characters: 93h4-283ed-93j2-je82
Random Characters: 93i4-283ed-93j2-je82
Hello My Name John
Random Characters: 93j4-283ed-93j2-je82
Nice To Meet You
Random Characters: 93k4-283ed-93j2-je82
How Is Your Day
Random Characters: 93l4-283ed-93j2-je82
```

**Output Raw Text File:**

```
93h4-283ed-93j2-je82
Random Characters: 93i4-283ed-93j2-je82
Hello My Name John
Random Characters: 93j4-283ed-93j2-je82
Nice To Meet You
Random Characters: 93k4-283ed-93j2-je82
How Is Your Day
Random Characters: 93l4-283ed-93j2-je82
```

---

Keep in mind I have left `Rem` comments for each process of the script. For any more help on the commands, type the following into a command prompt:

- `set /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `goto /?`
- Exc.